# How set C/C++ compiler for matlab?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

i've read several topics on this issue... but i'm not still able to figure out.
I've matlab 2013 and "MS Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable" both x86/x64 installed in Windows 8.
When i run "mex -setup" in matlab the following message appear:

Please choose your compiler for building MEX-files:

Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y

No supported SDK or compiler was found on this computer. 
For a list of supported compilers, see
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/win64.html

but the suggested file is for installing .NET 4 for windows 7, and i've windows 8. However, although i install this framework the mex -setup command still doesn't works.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to still be an issue with no straightforward solution. It took me a lot of searching, reading and trial and error to get a compiler to be recognized by mex.

In a nutshell, matlab 2013 doesn't support windows 8 SDK, but windows 7 SDK does not (easily) install on windows 8.

What worked for me:

The win7 SDK doesn't install on windows 8 because more recent versions of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable are already installed by default on Windows 8. You have to manually (from the control panel/programs/uninstal ...) uninstall all flavors of *VC++2010 redistributable* (x86 and x64).

See this Microsoft [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2717426/en-us) for details on how to do that.

After that I could install the SDK for win7 and got the compiler to be recognized by mex.

---

### Note:

I run on win8 32 bits, so what worked for me may not be perfect for everybody. During my searches on the subject i also noticed that many people often stumbled on 2 other setbacks:

- During the setup of win 7 SDK, .NET 4 doesn't install. => This is because .net4.5 is already shipped in windows 8. Again, uninstall .net4.5, then reinstall win7 SDK. (you can even reinstall .net4.5 if necessary after everything is done).
- Once everything is installed and mex happily found the compiler, error are raised during compilation tentative about a missing `ammintrin.h`. You may have to install MS Visual Studio C++ 2010 express then upgrade it to SP1. In this case follow the nicely detailed instructions in this [Matlab central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101105-how-do-i-install-microsoft-windows-sdk-7-1) article.

This last article linked seem to offer a complete solution, i didn't refer to it first in my answer because in some case (my case for example), only part of the setup described was necessary, so there was no point uninstalling/reinstalling a bunch of stuff. But be prepared that you may have to go though all of it ...